# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Hi I am getting the error

> "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format."

When pressing a delete button. But this error comes only in one web server. In other server it works fine. Again when locally running the application, there is no error but it will not firing the delete action. Any Idea??

Comment: What are you doing in delete button click ? are you trying to parse something for example date, it could be a culture issue on different server

Comment: I'm just setting the CommandArgument to the id, this is an image button & has OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" also there.

Comment: Please remove the CommandArgument and then check again..

Comment: Removed that also tried using normal button except image button. Still issue is there..

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did not use to be there. Locally it works perfect, but on server it does not. Local environment is Win8. Server is win2k3. I think it might be some Windows Updates that caused the error. Did you manage to solve it @Aruna?

Comment: install 4.5 framework in your pc. That solved this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes... This issue was solved by updating the .net framework to 4.5. The issue was with the framework with IE 10. Please check your server .net framework and Your local PC as well.

Just simply update the framework. I couldn't find any other solutions rather than this. :)

Comment: This is exactly the problem that I was having. It was in a PageRequestManager saying that the input string was not in the correct format. Migrated to 4.5 and IIS8 and everything worked as intended. Great job figuring it out. Cheers.

Comment: What can you do when you are unable to upgrade the server framework?  Doing so will cause other apps to break until we can get them updated.

Answer (score 3):

Found elsewhere the suggestion to use an Image  inside a Linkbutton.

Works well.   ImageButtons inside  Gridviews especially within update panels were always a pain.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1823287.aspx/2/10
Re: ImageButtons not working in IE10

Dec 05, 2012 04:38 PM|LINK

I couldn't get any of the above example to work for me, but I have an Image Button in a repeater within an update panel.  Anyway, I just replaced the Image Button with a Link Button wrapping an Image and everything is working again.

Comment: +1 Link posted in this answer has a link to the problem solution.

Answer (score 0):

if the delete image button and you don't need to install the .Net framework 4.5. All the time we are not able to change the framework versions. If we have window server 2003 r2 then we can't install the .Net framework 4.5. So in this case we can change the Image button to Link button. Here is the same source for link button to show as like image button in the asp.net

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="deleterow" runat="server" 
                                         CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")+","+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Facultykey") %>'
                                         OnCommand="DeleteFaculty" 
                                        Visible='<%# EnableControls(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem , "IsFacultyConfirmed"),2,DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem , "AFTId"),DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem , "FacultyKey"))%>' >
                                       <asp:Image ID="Delete" 
                                        ImageUrl="../App_Themes/Blue/images/buttons/delete.gif"
                                        runat="server"/></asp:LinkButton>
```

Since i personally suffer having windows server 2003 R2 and unable to install the .Net framework 4.5 and it will helps to solve the issue without touching the server config.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old question, but for people who will come here in future and read this, I will describe how I solved it.

My application was working for several years without problems and suddenly clients started to notice 'forewer waiting', page not refreshing because of above mentioned error (Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format.)

I had hard time to discover what was  main problem because there was no error while debugging .cs code. After searching a lot I discovered that someone proposed to disable PartialRendering...
(you can do it in .cs by ScriptManager1.EnablePartialRendering = false;
or in page by adding EnablePartialRendering="false")

So I disabled it, and voila... finally while debugging, error appeared in one function, and executiuon stopped like before but with more description. Cool, now I know where is enemy :-)
It is interesting that it wasn't hit at all while EnablePartialRendering is true.
Now execution wasn't stopped in Code Behind too, but finally some more text in browser window, this is what I got:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:

```
Line 1209:             Array.ConvertAll<DataRow, double>(
Line 1210:               dt.Select(),
Line 1211:               delegate (DataRow row) { return Convert.ToDouble(row[columnName].ToString()); }   
Line 1212:             );
Line 1213:            return GetMedianFromArray(values);
```

Problem was in Line: 1211