# asp:ImageButton OnClick event not firing in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, gridview

I am using **`<asp:ImageButton>`** inside `<asp:GridView>`  as below shown.

**Problem:**

This is working fine in Chrome and FireFox, but event not firing when I used **Internet Explorer**.
**.aspx Code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPatAppointment" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" runat="server"
     AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="capp_uniq_id"                                    
      OnRowDataBound="gvPatAppointment_RowDataBound" >
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeader" HeaderText="Cancel">
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton BorderStyle="None" ToolTip="Cancel Appointment" ID="ImgCancel" 
                     runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/NewTheme/images/CssImages/delete-file-icon.png" 
                     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("capp_uniq_id") %>'
                      OnClick="ImgCancel_Click"/>
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**.aspx.cs Code**

```
protected void ImgCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = string.Empty;
    mdpCancelAppt.Show();
    SelectedAppointment = string.Empty;
    ImageButton ImgCancel = (ImageButton)sender;
    SelectedAppointment = Convert.ToString(ImgCancel.CommandArgument.ToString());`

}
```

Comment: Share the source for you OnClick event please

Comment: Is IE logging any messages in your console?

Comment: seems some javascript error in your code.

Comment: @AntarrByrd - yes it's shows msg **`"SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format. "`**

Comment: okay thanks... I think This problem is specific with IE and there is no particular solution for this - so I will use <asp:LinkButton> instead <asp:imageButton>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to your error message

This is occurring because your submit button is an `input` with `type="image"` (As it is render as input type='image'). Therefore, coordinates are submitted with the form. Previous versions of Internet Explorer submit those coordinates as integers, but Internet Explorer 10 submits them as decimals.

There are a variety of ways to fix it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13299685/937084) and [this bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755419/asp-net-4-0-and-ie10-click-on-imagebutton-in-updatepanel-produces-error-click-on-normal-button-does-not) for some solutions.

### Edit 1

Similar Questions

1. [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516355/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception-input-string-was-not-in-a-c)
2. [SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265886/script5022-sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception-input-string-wa)

Comment: @Shekhar - okay thanks... I think This problem is related IE and there is no particular solution for this - so I will use **`<asp:LinkButton>`** instead  `<asp:imageButton>`